# Composer update and PHP short tags

Tags: php, composer-php, wamp

I have come across an issue with composer and PHP short tags `<?`.

Take this code below.

```
<?

    namespace SPACENAME;

    class generic_class {

        private $class_name = 'this_is_a_test';

        /**
         * This function is used to return the class name property.
         */
        public function some_function() {
            return true;
        }

    }

?>
```

If you notice, we have a class called `generic_class` and a comment that contains the words **class name**, and are using PHP's short tags `<?`

When I do a composer update my autoload class shows the following:

```
<?php

    // autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

    $vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
    $baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

    return array(
        'SPACENAME\name' => $vendorDir . '/the/path/to/generic_class.php'
    );

?>
```

It seems to pick up the words **class name** in the comment and treats that as a class definition instead of using the actual class definition of `generic_class`. However if I use PHP's full tags `<?php` then this issue doesn't happen and my autoload class is correct.

```
<?php

    // autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

    $vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
    $baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

    return array(
        'SPACENAME\generic_class' => $vendorDir . '/the/path/to/generic_class.php'
    );

?>
```

So, in one way I have fixed the issue by swapping my short tags to full tags. However I am currently working in a fairly large team who all use composer for the same project and do not get this issue with short tags. I can't see me being able to change their usage/opinion on short tags so I am hoping someone has a solution or at least an answer as to why this may be happening on my machine and no one elses?

I did try to google for the answer but came up with nothing, is there a composer setting that stops it recognizing short tags as valid php therefore it is unable to know what is code and what is a comment?

Information that might be helpful

- We all have the same OS (Windows).
- We are all on the same version of composer.
- We are all working from the same codebase.
- There are 8 of us working on the project at the moment.
- We all have our PHP servers set up differently, I am the only one who
  uses WAMPSERVER 3.

Comment: Changing the short tags to long tags is basically a download of [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) and running it on the codebase once to fix all the tags, then committing it. Oh, yes: And agreeing in the team that using them is a bad idea and should be avoided. Probably the harder part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need just to disable short tags in your configuration. Just set

```
short_open_tag=0
```

in your `php.ini`. Please, be careful: the php interpreter used by composed sometimes has a different `php.ini` with respect to the Apache version.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: I would not be able to disable php short tags as the majority of our in house framework uses them. I ideally need a way to get composer to recognize them. I will try and see if I can find a separate php.ini that composer uses, changing that might help! Thank you.

Comment: If you are able to run `php` from the console window, then you should just run `php -i` to get the whole configuration, including the path of `php.ini`. Obviously, changing the configuration for the composer should not effect the behaviour of your main interpreter. If the php.ini file is shared between them, try to split them.

Comment: It appears to have been an issue with php.ini